# What is the proper way to call a Rails API from App to App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api

I have 2 different Rails application and I want these apps to send and receive information via an API. What is the correct way to do this?

I was trying to use this resource but I don't quite understand it: http://api.rubyonrails.org/
(I am not sure how to make the call for the different methods. Some methods show an URL which I guess I wouldn't have too much problem implementing, but what if the application is within the same server, what would be the correct way to call a corresponding API method.)

Is there a recommended beginners resource out there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org) is Ruby on Rails documentation, so this is API of RoR. What you want is external HTTP, probably REST and probably JSON API.

There are many resources on building REST API's. In general you have to prepare some endpoints that application can send request to and handle responses.

Take a look i.e. on [railscast about using active model serializers](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers). This would be the part where you give other application endpoints to get or change data.

Normally you would stop here because in most cases you set API for other applications (like mobile or javascript applications). But in your case you will need something to send requests. There are many gems that allow that, but I find [Faraday gem](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) most useful.